# C# - Get PID or name of the process handle

Tags: c#, winapi, handles, memory-editing

I enumerate all handles of a process. I have process handle and now I want to know the PID of the process the handle is for. Here is the stuct I am using:

```
public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
public int ProcessID;
public byte ObjectTypeNumber;
public byte Flags; // 0x01 = PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE, 0x02 = INHERIT
public ushort Handle;
public int Object_Pointer;
public UInt32 GrantedAccess;
}
```

The ProcessID sadly of all my handles is the same as the PID of the program I am running (host).
It should be the Object_Pointer, but I am not sure how to use it. Now the Object_Pointer together with GrantedAccess matches the object address of the process the handle is for -  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlPD3.png)

It is weird though, since the GrantedAccess should be the level of access for the process and not part of the address.

Answer (score 1):

if we have process handle with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` or `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access right we can got it PID by [`GetProcessId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215(v=vs.85).aspx) function

and your definition of `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION` is wrong. obviously that `Object_Pointer` can not be int (4 bytes) when it must be `void*` (8 bytes on 64-bit system). correct definition of this structure is

```
struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO
{
    USHORT UniqueProcessId;
    USHORT CreatorBackTraceIndex;
    UCHAR ObjectTypeIndex;
    UCHAR HandleAttributes;
    USHORT HandleValue;
    PVOID Object;
    ULONG GrantedAccess;
};
```

but however much better use [`SystemExtendedHandleInformation`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01268) instead  [`SystemHandleInformation`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01220) and work with [`SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html#l01864)

Comment: The PID I get with GetProcessId is 0, Process Hacker confirms the handle is correct (0x184 in my case). If I GetProcessId with this handle I get 0. My code - https://puu.sh/ygb9J/815e650da4.png

Comment: If rename the SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION to your code I get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: @SergiyWontTell - if return 0 - need look last error. and in api clear stated that handle must have `PROCESS_QUERY_[LIMITED_]INFORMATION` access. at second - I not paste to you any code. if you got exception - this is only say that was error in my code. in any case this not change fact that my answer is correct